# Parsing XML Attributes with Python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse out all the green highlighted attributes (some sensitive things have been blacked out), I have a bunch of XML files all with similar formats, I already know how to loop through all of them individually them I am having trouble parsing out the specific attributes though.

[XML Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqknO.png)

I need the text in the attributes: `name="text1"`

from

```
project logLevel="verbose" version="2.0" mainModule="Main" name="text1">
```

`destinationDir="/text2"` from

```
put label="Put Files" destinationDir="/Trigger/FPDMMT_INBOUND">
```

`destDir="/text3"` from

```
copy disabled="false" version="1.0" label="Archive Files" destDir="/text3" suffix="">
```

I am using

```
import csv
import os
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(XMLfile_path)
item = tree.getroot()[0]
root = tree.getroot()
print (item.get("name"))
print (root.get("name"))
```

This outputs:

```
Main
text1
```

The item.get pulls the line at index [0] which is the first line root in the tree which is <module
The root.get pulls from the first line <project

I know there's a way to search for exactly the right part of the root/tree with something like:

```
test = root.find('./project/module/ftp/put')
print (test.get("destinationDir"))
```

I need to be able to jump directly to the thing I need and output the attributes I need.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to edit your question with a clean, preferably simplified, version of the xml; it's hard to help with just an image.

Comment: You'll have more luck getting a response if you edit down that XML to something just big enough to demonstrate the problem and post it with the question. Something we can use ourselves. It should be easy to load it into an example program that holds your best attempt and including that in this question also. Make it easy for us to help.

Comment: Please update the question with a VALID XML document - as text please.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified copy of your XML:

```
xml = '''<project logLevel="verbose" version="2.0" mainModule="Main" name="hidden">
    <module name="Main">
        <createWorkspace version="1.0"/>
        <ftp version="1.0" label="FTP connection to PRD">
            <put label="Put Files" destinationDir="destination1">
            </put>
        </ftp>
        <ftp version="1.0" label="FTP connection to PRD">
            <put label="Put Files" destinationDir="destination2">
            </put>
        </ftp>
        <copy disabled="false" destDir="destination3">
        </copy>
    </module>
</project>
'''

# solution using ETree
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

name = root.get('name')
ftp_destination_dir1 = root.findall('./module/ftp/put')[0].get('destinationDir')
ftp_destination_dir2 = root.findall('./module/ftp/put')[1].get('destinationDir')
copy_destination_dir = root.find('./module/copy').get('destDir')

print(name)
print(ftp_destination_dir1)
print(ftp_destination_dir2)
print(copy_destination_dir)

# solution using lxml
from lxml import etree as et

root = et.fromstring(xml)

name = root.get('name')
ftp_destination_dirs = root.xpath('./module/ftp/put/@destinationDir')
copy_destination_dir = root.xpath('./module/copy/@destDir')[0]

print(name)
print(ftp_destination_dirs[0])
print(ftp_destination_dirs[1])
print(copy_destination_dir)
```